# before avio_open() function is executed, it has no connection with RTMP server

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm a beginner of ffmpeg API. I think the function connecting to RTMP server is avio_open() function. In my code, before avio_open() function is executed, it has no connection with RTMP server. Whether I understand correctly.
I have a problem at this time : **the RTMP server does not find the key frame within 5 seconds after the client connects to the RTMP server, the server will close the connection.**
However, according to my understanding, the client has found the key frame before connecting to the server, so the server should also find the key frame. Why can't the key frame be found?

```
#include "/usr/local/include/libavcodec/avcodec.h"
#include "/usr/local/include/libavformat/avformat.h"
#include "/usr/local/include/libavfilter/avfilter.h"
#include "/usr/local/include/libavutil/mathematics.h"
#include "/usr/local/include/libavutil/time.h"

extern VideoDataStruct *VideoDataListHeader;
extern PushVideoStruct PushVideoInfo;
extern enum IsPushingVideo IsPushingVideoFlag;
extern UCHAR ChangeAnotherVideo;
typedef long long int64;


#define READ_BUF_LEN       1024*12

extern enum IsStopPushVideo StopPushVideoFlag;  

static int read_packet(void *opaque, uint8_t *buf, int buf_size)
{
    int64 dataLen = 0;

    while (dataLen < buf_size)
    {
        if ((VideoDataListHeader != NULL) && (VideoDataListHeader->flag == 1))
        {
            memcpy(&buf[dataLen], VideoDataListHeader->buf, sizeof(VideoDataListHeader->buf));
            dataLen += sizeof(VideoDataListHeader->buf);

            VideoDataListHeader->flag = 0;
            VideoDataListHeader = VideoDataListHeader->next;
        }
        else 
        {
            usleep(10000);
        }
    }
    return buf_size;
}

void *PushVideoFunction(void *arg)
{
    AVFormatContext *m_pFmtCtx = NULL;
    AVPacket pkt;   
    AVIOContext *m_pIOCtx = NULL;
    AVInputFormat *in_fmt = NULL;
    int ret = 0;
    unsigned int i = 0;
    int vid_idx =-1;
    unsigned char *m_pIOBuf = NULL;
    int m_pIOBuf_size = READ_BUF_LEN;
    int64 start_time = 0;
    int frame_index = 0;
    //const char *rtmp_url = "rtmp://192.168.1.108/mytv/01";
    char rtmp_url[140] = {0};
    memset(rtmp_url, 0, sizeof(rtmp_url));
    strcpy(rtmp_url, PushVideoInfo.VideoServer);
    CHAR fileName[64] = {0};

    avformat_network_init(); 
    if (strcmp(PushVideoInfo.VideoType, REAL_VIDEO) == 0) 
    {
        m_pIOBuf = (unsigned char*)av_malloc(m_pIOBuf_size);
        if(m_pIOBuf == NULL)
        {
            printf("av malloc failed!\n");
            goto end;
        }

    
        m_pIOCtx = avio_alloc_context(m_pIOBuf, m_pIOBuf_size, 0, NULL, read_packet, NULL, NULL);       
        if (!m_pIOCtx) 
        {
            printf("avio alloc context failed!\n");
            goto end;
        }

    
        m_pFmtCtx = avformat_alloc_context();
        if (!m_pFmtCtx)  
        {
            printf("avformat alloc context failed!\n");
            goto end;
        }


        //m_pFmtCtx->probesize = BYTES_PER_FRAME * 8;
        m_pFmtCtx->pb = m_pIOCtx;  
        ret = avformat_open_input(&m_pFmtCtx, "", in_fmt, NULL);
    }
    else if (strcmp(PushVideoInfo.VideoType, HISTORY_VIDEO) == 0) 
    {
        sprintf(fileName, "%s", VIDEO_FILE_FOLDER);
        sprintf(fileName+strlen(fileName), "%s", PushVideoInfo.VideoFile);
        ret = avformat_open_input(&m_pFmtCtx, fileName, NULL, NULL);
    }
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        printf("avformat open failed!\n");
        goto end;           
    }

    ret = avformat_find_stream_info(m_pFmtCtx, 0);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        printf("could not find stream info!\n");
        goto end;           
    }       
    for(i = 0; i < m_pFmtCtx->nb_streams; i++)
    {
        if((m_pFmtCtx->streams[i]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) && (vid_idx < 0))
        {
            vid_idx = i;
        }
    }

    AVFormatContext *octx = NULL;

    ret = avformat_alloc_output_context2(&octx, 0, "flv", rtmp_url);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        printf("avformat alloc output context2 failed!\n");
        goto end;
    }   

    av_init_packet(&pkt);    

    
    for (i = 0;i < m_pFmtCtx->nb_streams; i++)
    {
        AVCodec *codec = avcodec_find_decoder(m_pFmtCtx->streams[i]->codecpar->codec_id);
        AVStream *out = avformat_new_stream(octx, codec);
        ret = avcodec_parameters_copy(out->codecpar, m_pFmtCtx->streams[i]->codecpar);
        out->codecpar->codec_tag = 0;
    }

    ret = avio_open(&octx->pb, rtmp_url, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
    if (!octx->pb)
    {
        printf("avio open failed!\n");
        goto end;       
    }

    ret = avformat_write_header(octx, 0);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        printf("avformat write header failed!\n");
        goto end;           
    }

    start_time = av_gettime();
    AVStream *in_stream, *out_stream;
    AVRational time_base1;
    AVRational time_base;
    AVRational time_base_q;
    int64 calc_duration;
    int64 pts_time;
    int64 now_time;
    
    ChangeAnotherVideo = 0;
    while((!StopPushVideoFlag) && (ChangeAnotherVideo == 0))
    {
        ret = av_read_frame(m_pFmtCtx, &pkt);
        if (ret < 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        if (pkt.pts == AV_NOPTS_VALUE)
        {
            time_base1 = m_pFmtCtx->streams[vid_idx]->time_base;
            calc_duration = (double)AV_TIME_BASE/av_q2d(m_pFmtCtx->streams[vid_idx]->r_frame_rate);
            
            pkt.pts = (double)(frame_index*calc_duration)/(double)(av_q2d(time_base1)*AV_TIME_BASE);
            pkt.dts = pkt.pts;
            pkt.duration = (double)calc_duration/(double)(av_q2d(time_base1)*AV_TIME_BASE);
        }
        if (pkt.stream_index == vid_idx)
        {
            time_base = m_pFmtCtx->streams[vid_idx]->time_base;
            time_base_q = (AVRational){1, AV_TIME_BASE};            
            pts_time = av_rescale_q(pkt.dts, time_base, time_base_q);
            now_time = av_gettime() - start_time;
            if (pts_time > now_time)
            {
                av_usleep(pts_time - now_time);
            }
        }
        in_stream  = m_pFmtCtx->streams[pkt.stream_index];
        out_stream = octx->streams[pkt.stream_index];
        pkt.pts = av_rescale_q_rnd(pkt.pts, in_stream->time_base, out_stream->time_base, (enum AVRounding)(AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF|AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX));
        pkt.dts = av_rescale_q_rnd(pkt.dts, in_stream->time_base, out_stream->time_base, (enum AVRounding)(AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF|AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX));
        pkt.duration = av_rescale_q(pkt.duration, in_stream->time_base, out_stream->time_base);
        pkt.pos = -1;
        if(pkt.stream_index == vid_idx)
        {
            printf("Send %8d video frames to output URL\n",frame_index);
            frame_index++;
        }
        ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(octx, &pkt);
        if (ret < 0)
        {
            goto end;
        }
        av_packet_unref(&pkt);
    }
    
end:
    printf("---------------------------------stop push video -------------------------------------------\n");
    StopPushVideoFlag = NO_STOP_PUSH;
    IsPushingVideoFlag = NO_PUSHING;    
    ChangeAnotherVideo = 0;
    avformat_close_input(&m_pFmtCtx);
    if (octx)
    {
        avio_closep(&octx->pb);
        avformat_free_context(octx);
    }
    /* note: the internal buffer could have changed, and be != avio_ctx_buffer */
    if (m_pIOCtx) 
    {
        av_freep(&m_pIOCtx->buffer);
        av_freep(&m_pIOCtx);
    }

    if (ret < 0) 
    {
        printf("Error occured : %s\n", av_err2str(ret));
        //return 1;
    }
    pthread_exit((void*)"push video end!"); 
    
}


void PushVideo(void)
{
    int ret = 0;
    pthread_t pushVideoThread;

    ret = pthread_create(&pushVideoThread, NULL, PushVideoFunction, NULL);
    if(ret != 0)
    {
        printf("error : push video thread create failed!\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("(debug) push video thread create success!\n");
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About not found key frame:
Because when I cache video data, I don't cache it with SPS, PPS, I frame, so these errors will be reported when the AA function is executed.
Although these errors will not affect the subsequent streaming process, in order to reduce the display of these errors, I found the SPS & PPS & I frame before caching data.

About disconnect:
The client has a Nalu of type 0x0a, which the server doesn't know. Therefore, the server sends a FIN message and disconnects the connection. It's not because the key frame can't be found.